# Sharing One screen using webrtc

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, screensharing

I have a dual monitor. I would like to know how could i share only one monitor at a time.

Currently i am able  to share both the monitors using chrome.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

To have a choice on what to share you could use the desktopCapture API and use "window" as the DesktopCaptureSourceType.  It'll popup a window allowing you to choose which window to share...

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture

Example usage ...
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#desktop-capture-example

Comment: Can i do it without using desktopCapture extensions?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use the desktopCapture outside an extension ... "chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia is designed as an extension API, and will not be accessible from drive-by web, for security reasons"  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/discuss-webrtc/j6jmyBFt9QI/6cjiksWiYaEJ